# Handle empty value in required select not working in MSIE

Tags: html, forms, required

I have this HTML:

```html
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="#">
  <select id="u2p" name="u2p" size="10" multiple="multiple" required="required">
    <option value="">[None]</option>
    <option value="1">Firefox</option>
    <option value="2">Chrome</option>
    <option value="3">MS Explorer</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit1" />
</form>
```

I use `<option value="">[None]</option>` because it is not possible to clear a select list once an item is selected.

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in MSIE. When a user selects `[None]` in MSIE and tries to submit the form then he gets red border around select and a "You must choose an item from the list" message. Submitting is not possible.

Does anybody knows an easy workaround for this? I would prefer to keep `value=""`, otherwise I have to change a lot of code like this:

```
// Select '[None]' if nothing is selected:
if ( $("#u2p :selected").length == 0 ) $("#u2p").val("");

// Clear all values (1,2,3) if user selects '[None]'
$("select").change(function() { 
   if ( $.inArray("", $(this).val()) != -1 ) $(this).val(""); 
});
```

Comment: So you want the required to not be required??? Why not remove required and write your own validation?

Comment: @mplungjan, in deed that would be the simplest solution. Select nothing is the same as selecting `[None]`, so there is no need for `required`. Also it looks like that you can unselect an item while holding `Ctrl`-Key - I am sure this was not possible in older browsers. In an older application I created a separate "Clear" button due to this.

Comment: Ah, right. I think it was likely always possible, but I have used multiple maybe twice in 20 years

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit weird that you have required on the select but want to send empty if the required "NONE" has been selected. Use CTRL-Click to deselect if you want to get rid of the NONE or the required.

If not, then how about this:

```js
function toggleU2p() {
  var show = $("#u2pcheck").is(":checked");
  $("#u2pdiv").toggle(show);
  if (!show) {
    $("#u2p option:selected").prop("selected",false);
  }
}
$(function() {
  $("#u2pcheck").on("click",toggleU2p);
  toggleU2p();
});
```

```css
#u2pdiv {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="#">
  <input type="checkbox" id="u2pcheck" />Do you use a browser?
  <div id="u2pdiv">
    <select id="u2p" name="u2p" size="3" multiple="multiple" required="required">
      <option value="1">Firefox</option>
      <option value="2">Chrome</option>
      <option value="3">MS Explorer</option>
    </select>
  </div><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit1" />
</form>
```

Comment: Use CTRL-Click to deselect was not possible in older browsers. I am working only occasionally with HTML, looks like I did not notice introduction of this feature.